# Support Minimum Resolution For Opening Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a website such that it does not open on displays below a certain screen resolution, say 1024 X 768 and displays an error message on unsupported resolutions.

I think this might be done with some sort of JS, but I was not able to do it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can use media queries in CSS to achieve that

Comment: @VincentG I'd be able to know the resolution but how would I display a not supported alert on the page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with jQuery `resize()` function

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/bk1v2xt7/)

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 400){
    alert('too SMALL !');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have an overlay `<div>` that has the error message you're looking to display in the event that the screen size is too small. Then using media queries, display on or off `display: none;` or `display: block;`

You can use that in conjunction with javascript to test to see if that `<div>` is visible then either run the application or not run the application.